# Xamarin Android Build Errors After Adding MvvmCross.Plugins.Fingerprint Package 2.1.3

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, fingerprint, biometrics

I need help. Again and again.

My app was building and running fine after migrating to AndroidX.  I need to implement Biometrics, so I installed MvvmCross.Plugins.Fingerprint.  Now I get 3 errors:

1. 'Mvx' does not contain a definition for 'Warning' (CS0117)
2. 'Resource' does not contain a definition for 'Layout' (CS0117)
3. 'Resource.Id' does not contain a definition for 'text1' (CS0117)

I'm going to post this on the GitHub page for the package too.

I googled all of errors, but nothing looks promising.

Thanks!
Larry

[image]

Comment: For the error CS0117, if your project works well brfore, delete the obj and bin folder to clean and rebuild the project. Normally, this error would be fixed.

Comment: That did not work unfortunately.  I had tried that already.  Any other ideas?  $200 donation for helping me fix this.  Thanks!

Comment: If the code works before and you do not change the code, I think the error would not affect the project to run. Have you try to uninstall `MvvmCross.Plugins.Fingerprint`? I want to confirm the error caused by this or not.

Comment: I reverted the code and verified that it ran.

Comment: If it is possible, could you provide a sample code for me to test with the `MvvmCross.Plugins.Fingerprint` package?

Comment: Are you available to help via screen sharing?  I'll make a donation!  Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227860/discussion-between-larry-feldman-and-wendy-zang-msft).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely that the plugin is targeting MvvmCross 6.0.0, while you are on 7.x.x since you are mentioning AndroidX.

The MvvmCross.Plugins.Fingerprint package doesn't much else than just registering the Fingerprint in the IoC container for you.

So instead try just adding the [`Plugin.Fingerprint`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.Fingerprint/) package to your project. Then in `Setup.cs` you can register this yourself in a override of `InitializeLastChance` or any other relevant lifecycle method there:

```
protected override void InitializeLastChance()
{
    base.InitializeLastChance();

    Mvx.IoCProvider.LazyConstructAndRegisterSingleton(() => CrossFingerprint.Current);
}
```

Now you can resolve `IFingerprint` in your ViewModels.

Comment: Thanks for responding!  I need to implement Face and Iris detection too.  I believe MvvmCross.Plugins.Fingerprint package was enhanced to handle Face and Iris.  The Git page says to migrate to Android X.  What do you think?

Comment: Not at all, the _only_ thing in there is a Plugin.cs file, see for yourself: https://github.com/smstuebe/xamarin-fingerprint/tree/master/src/MvvmCross.Plugins.Fingerprint

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  Are you available to help via screensharing?  Donation available!  Thanks.

Comment: When I attempted to add the following, I get an error 'Mvx' does not contain a definition for 'IOCProvider'.  Thanks!

Mvx.IoCProvider.LazyConstructAndRegisterSingleton(() => CrossFingerprint.Current);

Comment: It's there. Has been since MvvmCross 6. https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/5354b207f2f626035a631b3762642ebdc3b48172/MvvmCross/Mvx.cs#L17